# How to listen to events between classes with no inheritance in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

In the code below, the event "myEvent" dispatched in class A is never listened in class C. Do you see where the problem is?

```
Class A extends EventDispatcher{
    A(){
        dispatchEvent(new Event("myEvent"));
    }
}

Class B extends A{
    ...
}

Class C extends EventDispatcher{
    method(){
        addEventListenet("myEvent", onresult);

        var ob:A = new B();

        ob.method();
    }

    onResult(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, your `A` object in creation does not know wherer to dispatch the event "myEvent", and dispatching to self does not do a thing, because there is nowhere for the event to go, even if you'll tell it to bubble. You need to provide a listening object to either the entire `A` class, or to a specific object of type `A`, so that that object will be the source of `dispatchEvent()` call, becoming the target for the dispatched event.

```
class A { // no inheritance needed
    public static var listener:EventDispatcher;
    public function A() {
        if (listener) listener.dispatchEvent("myEvent");
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to create a static class just for the purpose of sending broascast events, implement its functionality as you would do with an `EventDispatcher` (use internal instance of `EventDispatcher` to add and remove listeners, dispatch events and check if there's someone listening), and use that class's interface to register with any event type that you're intending to send to all who will listen.

```
public class Broadcaster {
    private static var _instance:EventDispatcher=new EventDispatcher();
    public static function addBroadcastListener
      (s:String,f:Function,c:Boolean=false,p:int=0,w:Boolean=false) {
        if (_instance) _instance.addEventListener(s,f,c,p,w);
    }
    // etc, just make wrappers for EventDispatcher functions
}
```

Then in `C.method` you do:

```
Broadcaster.addBroadcastListener("myEvent",onresult);
```

And in A() you do:

```
Broadcaster.dispatchEvent(new Event("myEvent"));
```

Comment: This answer is a bit frustrating to me. The first sentence ".. dispatching to self does not do a thing" is completely wrong.
The entire event system works as the class doesn't care who's listening to the event and why. It simply dispatches.
The whole bunch is just making things more complicated, having a third class with static properties. IF he defines A class in C, he just needs to add listener TO A class, exactly like Petr said.

Comment: The trouble is that the `dispatchEvent()` is located in the constructor, so it first dispatches the event, then returns the newly created reference to be assigned to `ob`. Of course, should he need an event be dispatched *after* the creation of the object, in some method, then Petr's answer is correct, you get the reference, attach a listener, then call the method. But if one needs to dispatch an event right from the constructor, then this approach cannot be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach listener to the the `ob`:

```
Class C extends EventDispatcher{
    method(){
        var ob:A = new B();
        ob.addEventListener("myEvent", onresult);
        ob.method();
    }

    onResult(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to precise that the method in class A that dispatches the event in the constructor of the class. So I can't put the listener on the obj because it would be too late to listen the event.

Comment: I see, is passing event recipient object as an argument to constructor of class `A` an option?

Comment: @PetrHrehorovsky Don't forget that an event listener function still needs a parameter of `Event` type, or else you face an argument count mismatch exception.

Comment: @Vesper Indeed. I just copied code from the question. I will fix when I agree with yo_haha on solution.

Comment: Dispatching an event in constructor is absolutely strange for me. Because the class that instantiates the class knows what's going on, and the event can be dispatched THERE, not inside the new class. Event system in Flash is a bit like a tree - you need to know where to listen and where to dispatch. You just need a better structure for the code, instead of dispatching things when they instantiate.

Comment: @Andrey The constructor calls a remote service. When the the instance of A receives an answer from the service, it dispatches the event "myEvent" so that class C can use the properties of A instance that were received from the remote service.

Comment: @yo_haha Then the constructor should be asynchronous, if you're using a remote service. If so, use this answer as a guidance.

Comment: @PetrHrehorovsky Passing the event recipient in the class A constructor is doesn't seem to me very suitable. The event recipient us like a "controller" for the "entity" class A.

Comment: @Vesper The constructor does an asynchronous call to the remote service. The call and the answer of the remote service are done inside class A. When the answer is received the event is dispatched. I didn't put all that in my code for simplicity.

Comment: Then I think that Vesper's answer should address your problem.